# NotImplementedError:font module not available

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, py2exe

I have written the following codes in the setup file and include both sdl_ttf.dll", "SDL.dll in the default folder. 
But, it shows an error message:

```
NotImplementedError:font module not available
<Import error: DLL load failed:can't find assigned module>
```

The code

```
from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe,sys,os
import pygame

setup(console=['blackjack.py'])

origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
       if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ["sdl_ttf.dll", "SDL.dll"]:
               return 0
       return origIsSystemDLL(pathname)
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL

pygamedir = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]
os.path.join(pygamedir, pygame.font.get_default_font()),
os.path.join(pygamedir, 'SDL.dll'),
os.path.join(pygamedir, 'SDL_ttf.dll')
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your check

```
if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ["sdl_ttf.dll", "SDL.dll"]:
```

will not work, since you're calling `lower()` on the filename, but use `SDL.dll` instead of `sdl.dll`, so py2exe will not include the sdl library.

You could also try to use [this](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) script from the pygame wiki.